# Superclass' fields: private+accessors vs protected

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

Snippet #1:

```java
public abstract class SuperClass {
    protected int i;   
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public void method() {
        i = doAnythingWithI(i); // for example
    }
}
```

Snippet #2:

```java
public abstract class SuperClass {
    private int i;    
    protected int getI() {
        return i;
    }    
    protected int setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public void method() {
        setI(doAnythingWithI(getI())); // for example
    }
}
```

Any reason why using one snippet instead of the other one? What is the most common way to process?

Comment: I would say you would most likely use the former code snippet as opposed to the latter code snippet. There is no point in properly encapsulating `i` because you are not even performing any operations with your set method, so you are just adding more things on the stack, possibly slowing down your program.

Comment: In the first snippet `SuperClass` and `SubClass` are tightly coupled, which makes me question, why to introduce `SubClass` at all. In the second snippet the field `i` is fully exposed by the `get/set` pair, which again couples `SubClass` tightly to its parent. This raises the same question again: Why introduce `SubClass` at all.
Furthermore the snippets look like you want to use inheritance for implementation but you should rather use it for behaves as, instead of is implemented as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the more common uses of an abstract class is to have abstract methods that are not implemented in abstract class, but implemented in subclasses in java program.  This is obviously not your use case.   However, an abstract class can also be used as a way of preventing someone from instantiating a class that is supposed to be extended first.  I am assuming this is your desire.

Furthermore, I assume the trivial nature of the example is just for illustration.  Having two classes to "manage" a single primitive 'int' would probably be suspect otherwise!

Given this and the two choices Snippet #2 is closer to being correct.  The reason for this being the desire of a "type" to encapsulate state, data, and behavior.  Snippet #1 violates this and would usually be discouraged.

The method "doAnythingWithI" begs discussion though.  It is not really declared in your examples.  If it operates solely upon "i" and is not subject to alteration by a concrete class, then it also belongs in the abstract base class.

If it can vary with multiple implementations that extend the SuperClass, then it should probably be defined as an abstract method in the SuperClass and implemented by the sub-classes.